# In ADF, can we use one Integration Runtime for two different on-premise data sources?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

IN Azure Data Factory, is it possible to use one Integration Run time to connect two different On-Premise data sources?

Scenario:
I have created one self hosted Integration Runtime installed in Virtual Machine for DB2 Database which is On-Premise DB.

I wanted to add one more On-Premises DB which is SQL Server.
Is it possible to use the existing Self Hosted Integration Runtime for SQL Server On Prem DB?

I have tried connecting to existing Self Hosted Integration Runtime in Linked Service. The test connection is getting failed.

I know, some where access privileges required for SQL Server DB either from VM or from the SQL Server to make the connectivity possible via existing Integration Runtime.

Connectivity to SQL Server DB is getting failed, while I use the existing IR, which is already used for DB2.

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Please mark the correct answer as solved or leave a comment if you are still facing some issues thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You can find this in this document [Considerations for using a self-hosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir):

A single self-hosted integration runtime can be used for multiple on-premises data sources. A single self-hosted integration runtime can be shared with another data factory within the same Azure Active Directory tenant. For more information, see [Sharing a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#sharing-the-self-hosted-integration-runtime-with-multiple-data-factories).

When you want add a another on premise DB, you can try like this:

New link service:
[image]

Add another on premise DB:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse self-hosted IR.

Probably issue with connectivity lies somewhere else.

You can test this by logging into that VM via RDP and running tests either with SSMS to test connectivity or run simple PowerShell command to test network

```
Test-NetConnection "<server_address>" -port 1433
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Note that adding more nodes as part of self-hosted IR (integration runtime) is part of highly available and making sure that there is no SPOF (single point of failure) with one on-premise data gateway.

This is no relation with the number of on-premise data sources which can be connected from services launched in Azure.